# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable when i launching my website at openshift

Tags: openshift

When I launched my url from openshift it was showing me below error

> ## Service Temporarily Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
>
> Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at app-domain.rhcloud.com Port 80"

please give me some advise how i solve that problem ?

Comment: Try restarting your app.

Answer (score 6):

The best way for you to troubleshoot things like this is to check your logs on your gear. You can do this one of two ways.

First you can use the `rhc tail` command to tail out your log files:
`rhc tail -a <yourappname>`

The second way to look at your logs is to ssh in directly and go to the logs directory.
`rhc ssh <your appname>`

`cd $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the answer above me...

as a noob I would have thought that the 503 error meant that Redhat was doing some sort of routine maintenance, given that Monday was a holiday.  It never occurred to me that it meant a coding problem, given the wording of the error.

The log showed me that I'd forgotten to "git add..." a particular folder in my project which was necessary after the last push.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your account and restart the app

[image]